# Aop and Mono argument

Tags: spring, project-reactor, spring-aop

I have method

```java
Mono<ReceiptResponse> a01(Mono<DefaultBeneficiaryBankRequest> request)
```

and aspect

```java
    @Around("callAtMyServiceSecurityAnnotation(request)")
    @Order(1)
    public Object scheduleTimeout(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Mono<?> request) {
        Mono<?> retVal = (Mono)joinPoint.proceed();
        return retVal.doOnSuccess(i -> {
            ...
            someMethod(<request.value>)// <-- How I can get requets value here?
            ...
        });
    }
```

How I can get request value as someMethod argument?

Comment: Could you please update the question with code to test the usecase locally ?

Comment: I think you are lucky this time because I can guess what you want to know, but actually your question is unclear and my guess might be wrong. Before you post any new question next time, please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and always try to ask questions in that style.

Answer (score 0):

The information in your question is incomplete, but to me it seems your pointcut `callAtMyServiceSecurityAnnotation(request)` already captures the request and forwards it to your advice method as `Mono<?> request` parameter. So the answer to your question is simple: Just use `request` in order to get access to the request argument.

You do not show your actual pointcut, but assuming it is something like (untested, writing just freestyle because I do not have a test case from you to try it on)

```java
@Pointcut("within(my.package.MyTargetClass) && execution(* a01(*)) && args(request)")
public void callAtMyServiceSecurityAnnotation(Mono<?> request) {}
```

it should just work.

Comment: I cant understand how I can get request value for using in retVal.doOnSuccess.
I found only  
  
        AtomicReference<Object> reference = new AtomicReference<>();  
        request = request.doOnNext(reference::set);  
        Mono<?> retVal = (Mono)joinPoint.proceed(new Object[]{request});  
but it looks durty.

Comment: Some moderator must have deleted my previous comment which was not very polite, and I agree that I should not have written it the way I did. So I like to apologise and rephrase: I do not understand your follow-up question and might have misunderstood your whole question in the first place, which is why I already asked for an MCVE. If you extend your sample code to let it speak for itself, we will have fewer communication problems in plain prose. :-) Every capable programmer can understand a problem if she can copy and run a complete set of sample classes.